# KY-022 IR receiver, LED always on, no output

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, led, ir

I've been trying to use a KY-022 to read IR signals. However no output is being produced and the LED on the board is constantly on.

Board: Arduino Uno R3

I followed the procedure found [here](https://arduinomodules.info/ky-022-infrared-receiver-module/).

The code:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 11;

IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // In case the interrupt driver crashes on setup, give a clue
  // to the user what's going on.
  Serial.println("Enabling IRin");
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  Serial.println("Enabled IRin");
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

The output:

```
Enabling IRin
Enabled IRin
```

The LED is constantly on, it should come on when there's a signal received. However this is not shown in the output. :/ I don't know what to do.

Pictures:

[image: Board!]
[image: Board-upside-down, top-row corresponding to Signal!]
[image: Setup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to look at is the circuit board. Are they using the resistor and LED to indicate the board is receiving power? The data sheet has a schematic showing several passive components in the "3. ApplicationCircuit" section. Here is a copy of the schematic I have used that worked with the IRremote library (Version 0.1 July, 2009 - Copyright 2009 Ken Shirriff).

[image]

Comment: I'll be honest with you, I'm completely new to this, I think the LED is connected to Signal and 5V...?

Comment: If its any help, if I dont have the reciever plugged in, I still get the same output, that it has been enabled

Comment: Let's try something simple to begin with. Add a 10k ohm or 15k ohm resistor between 5V and the circuit board output pin. Try the "IRrecvDump.ino" sketch that comes with the library (this sketch seems to provide more information about the possible type of remote you have).

Comment: I think I added the 10k resistor correctly.. nothing, no output, led is still on

Comment: I don't think the LED will flash or turn ON when an IR signal is received. Unfortunately I can not see the bottom of the circuit board in the product link you have provided so I can't be 100% certain that the LED is just a "power indicator". Could you edit your question and add a picture showing how you have everything connected?

Comment: I added the pictures! sorry for the hold up, had school and stuff, hope that helps you help me

Comment: The LED indicates power to the circuit board and will not turn on and off with a incoming IR signal. The only thing missing from your pictures is the 10 - 15k ohm pull-up resistor between 5V and the signal output. Try several different types of remote controls with the "IRrecvDump.ino" sketch. My Apple TV remote and several of my TV/cable box remotes work with the same type of IR sensor you are using. If you have access to an oscilloscope, the IR sensor could be tested for an output signal. It's possible the IR sensor is defective.

Comment: I have this IR led, an the led in the ky-022 only turn on when receive data.

Comment: Sorry for the very late update, turns out the component itself wasn't working so I got a replacement and all is fine! Slowly beginning to understand electronics, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I "fried" my IR receiver.

Everything was fine and working until I accidentally reversed ground and +5v when putting my project back together after a tear down. 
After correcting the wiring, the LED stayed on, and no reading was coming out.

Did you ever get any pins wrong?

This video show the correct wiring.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFpAqG90zY0